# Replacing string characters in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string which is a sentence or two long (more than one word). In that sentence there will be a hash-tagged word e.g. `#word`. This needs to be replaced with `*word*`.

If the sentence is:

```
Today the weather is very nice #sun
```

It should become:

```
Today the weather is very nice *sun*
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is an overly duplicated question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a regular expression, like this:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"#(\w+)", "*$1*");
```

Comment: How does that get an * at the end of the word though?

Comment: @user2256772 I didn't see your edit about SO stripping out your asterisks. See my updated answer.

Comment: How about adding a `\b` at the end of the pattern?

Comment: What is the \b for? p.s.w.g your answer works fine on the text so far. Thanks !

Comment: @user2256772 `\b` ensures the pattern ends in a word boundary.

Comment: @SinaIravanian I don't think `\b` wouldn't add anything to pattern. It identifies a word boundary, however, the end of the word `(\w+)` will be a boundary anyway. Can you think of any case where that would change the behavior of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 string text = "Today the weather is very nice #sun";

 int startindex = text.Indexof('#'); 

 int endindex = text.IndexOf(" ", startIndex);

 text = text.Replace(text.substring(startIndex, 1), "*")
 text = text.Replace(text.substring(endindex, 1), "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string theTag = "sun";
string theWord = "sun";

string tag = String.Format("#{0}", theTag);
string word = String.Format("*{0}*", theWord);

string myString = "Today the weather is very nice #sun";
myString = myString.Replace(tag, word);
```

Comment: Problem is the word could be anything, not just sun

Comment: @user2256772 If you use the String.Format to create the tag to replace, like in the above code, then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

No fancy functions or libraries just common sense and solves your problem. It supports as many hashed words as you would like.

To demonstrate how it works I have created 1 TextBox and 1 Button in a c# form but you could use this code in console or pretty much anything.

```
      string output = ""; bool hash = false;
        foreach (char y in textBox1.Text)
        {
            if(!hash) //checks if 'hash' mode activated
            if (y != '#') output += y; //if not # proceed as normal
            else { output += '*'; hash = true; } //replaces # with *
            else if (y != ' ') output += y; // when hash mode activated check for space
            else { output += "* "; hash = false; } // add a * before the space
        } if (hash) output += '*'; // this is needed in case the hashed word ends the sentence
        MessageBox.Show(output);
```

and behold

```
Today the weather is very nice #sun
```

becomes

```
Today the weather is very nice *sun*
```

here is the same code but in method form for you to pop right in your code

```
   public string HashToAst(string sentence)
    {
        string output = ""; bool hash = false;
        foreach (char y in sentence)
        {
            if (!hash)
                if (y != '#') output += y;
                else { output += '*'; hash = true; } // you can change the # to anything you like here
            else if (y != ' ') output += y;
            else { output += "* "; hash = false; } // you can change the * to something else if you want
        } if (hash) output += '*';                 // and here also
        return output;
    }
```

to demonstrate how you could modify this below is a customizable version

```
    public string BlankToBlank(string sentence,char search,char highlight)
    {
        string output = ""; bool hash = false;
        foreach (char y in sentence)
        {
            if (!hash)
                if (y != search) output += y;
                else { output += highlight; hash = true; }
            else if (y != ' ') output += y;
            else { output += highlight+" "; hash = false; }
        } if (hash) output += highlight;
        return output;
    }
```

So the search would search for the character before the word and the highlight char will surround the word. Word being defined as characters until it reaches a space or the end of the string.